# Create watermark from black and white image using python

Tags: python, image

I’m very new to using python and image manipulation.

I have an image that I want to place over another image. The image is black and white and I only want the black part to be placed. I want to remove the white part.

[image]

I essentially want to create a watermark that I can place anywhere on an image.
Here is an example image on which I want to put the watermark.

[image]

[This blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pillow-creating-a-watermark/) post talks about making a watermark on an image. But I don’t want the entire image, just the black part of my watermark.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in your question.

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Write some code instead of asking us to do it.  What python library are you using?  What you tried so far?  What's the expected output image? Post info here instead of external links that will break in time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754852/how-to-set-alpha-value-of-a-pixel-in-python or even better modify your water image so it has a transparent rather than white background.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-alpha_composite-method/

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Overlaying one image on top of another? Replacing a colour with transparency? Setting the opacity of an image when overlaying? Reading the images into your program, or writing the result? Please share your code and be specific about where you're stuck. StackOverflow is here to help, but not to write your code for you.

Comment: @AllanWind and peter -- sorry for the bad question guys! i'll close.

Comment: with `PIL` or `numpy` (or `cv2`) you could read black and white image and duplicate it as alpha channel and you would have transparent image. And next you can use different functions in `PIL` or `numpy` to add two images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PIL` (or `cv2` with `numpy`) to make it.

Because you have black and white image so you can duplicate it, reverse it and put it as alpha channel to get transparency in place of white pixels.

Next you can `resize` it to expected size (I use size of second image) and you can `paste` it on second image in selected place (I use `(0,0)`) and it will put without transparent pixels. Images doesn't have to be the same size.

You can use other function to make other modification and get different effect. Some of functions may need to use images with the same size.

Doc: [Pillow.Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

import PIL
print(PIL.__version__)

# --- load ---

img1 = Image.open('Z9yFZ.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('Uh4LU.jpg')

# --- alpha channel ---

R,G,B = img1.split()
gray  = img1.convert('L')
alpha = ImageChops.invert(gray)

img1 = Image.merge('RGBA', [R,G,B,alpha])

# --- resize ---

img1.thumbnail(img2.size)

# --- merge ---

img2.paste(img1, (0,0), img1) # second `img1` as `mask`

img2.show()

# --- save ---

img2.save('result.jpg')
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I never test it but module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/index.html) (which uses [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/)) has function [watermark](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/wand/image.html?highlight=watermark#wand.image.BaseImage.watermark)

---

**EDIT:**

I created code like this:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from wand.color import Color

import wand
print(wand.version.VERSION)
print(wand.version.MAGICK_VERSION)

# --- load ---

img1 = Image(filename='Z9yFZ.jpg')  # has to use `filename=`
img2 = Image(filename='Uh4LU.jpg')  # has to use `filename=`

# --- alpha channel ---

#img1.alpha_channel = 'background'

#color = Color('#FFFFFF')  # white
color = Color('white')    # white
#color = Color('#000000')  # black
#color = Color('black')    # black
#color = img1.background_color
ten_percent = int(65535*0.1)  # remove similar colors (65535 = 2^16-1)

img1.transparent_color(color, alpha=0.0, fuzz=ten_percent)

# --- resize ---

w, h = img2.size
img1.transform(resize=f"{w}x{h}>")

# --- merge ---

img2.watermark(img1, left=0, top=0, transparency=0.5)  # transparent, looks good even without `fuzz=ten_percent` 
#img2.composite(img1, left=0, top=0)                    # not transparent, looks better with `fuzz=ten_percent`

display(img2)

# --- save ---

img2.save(filename='result.jpg')  # has to use `filename=`
```

[image]

Comment: I added example with `Wand`

Comment: Wow!!! You're awesome. Thank you. I really appreciate it. Super cool. I was playing around with PIL to no avail. Thank you, thank you.

Comment: My other answer: [python - Watermarking: pasting rotated text to empty image - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910445/watermarking-pasting-rotated-text-to-empty-image/62930639#62930639)